# Kubernetes: what do Non-Resource URLs and Resource Names mean in ClusterRole?

Tags: kubernetes

Here is the output when checking the detail of a specific cluster role. what do Non-Resource URLs and Resource Names mean in the result?

```
controlplane ~ kubectl describe clusterrole node-admin

Name:         node-admin
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
PolicyRule:
  Resources  Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs
  ---------  -----------------  --------------  -----
  nodes      []                 []              [get watch list create delete]
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [API docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.23/#policyrule-v1-rbac-authorization-k8s-io)

> **NonResourceURLs** is a set of partial urls that a user should have access to. *s are allowed, but only as the full, final step in the path Since non-resource URLs are not namespaced, this field is only applicable for ClusterRoles referenced from a ClusterRoleBinding. Rules can either apply to API resources (such as "pods" or "secrets") or non-resource URL paths (such as "/api"), but not both.

ClusterRoles are about giving permissions to some subjects to do some things. Usually those things involve interacting with RESTful resources like Pods, Services, other built-in resources, or custom resources coming from CustomResourceDefinitions. But there are other URLs not related to resources that you might want to control access to. The docs give `/healthz` as an example endpoint:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-examples

> **ResourceNames** is an optional white list of names that the rule applies to. An empty set means that everything is allowed.

As previously mentioned, usually ClusterRoles are about giving permissions to do stuff with resources. Normally, when you name a type of resource, the allowed verbs apply to all resources of that type. So if you allow deletion on the `pods` resources, the ClusterRole allows deletion of all pods. However, maybe you only want to allow deletion of specific pods, say one called `nginx-0`. You would put that name in the `ResourceNames` list.